# Google API returns blank columns

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

Good time a day. I want to add Excel-sheet file to Google Sheet with using API.

I wrote this code:

```
rngData = ws.Range('C1').CurrentRegion()



response = drive_service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=gsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range='C1',
    body=dict(
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        values=rngData
    )
).execute()
```

My Excel file sheet looks like in this picture:
[image: Excel-sheet]

In result I got two blank columns in Google Sheet. How can I delete this columns or choose correct range? I want to get as same result as in Excel.
[image: Google Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

In your function try to change the range where you want the results to be appended like this for example:

```
ngData = ws.Range('A1').CurrentRegion()



response = drive_service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=gsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range='A1',
    body=dict(
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        values=rngData
    )
).execute()
```

Is there a reason you used a region starting from C1?

Comment: I did it, but there are not full information inserted in Google.